# PCI Express device does not initialize properly after extended log off

Tags: windows-xp, power-management, pci-express

Ok, so I'm at my wit's end with this one.

I work on a system which utilizes a video capture board plugged into the PCI Express bus on a Windows XP SP3 x86 machine.  At one specific customer site we have an issue with this board.  Their workflow is to use the machine during the day and log off at night.  When they arrive back at the office in the morning they log back in, but the card does not function properly.

The manufacturer's low level utilities are unable to communicate with the board, but Windows does "see" it (via the Device Manager).  I have not received much help from the manufacturer thus far, only that it is specific to this customer's environment, which I already know.

So, my question here is; does there exist any sort of OS setting which could cause this sort of behavior?  I'm assuming the PCI-E bus is being shut down, put into a low power state, or something similar and that the board is not properly "waking up" when the user logs back in.  I could be wrong of course.

I have checked the power options and the system is set to never go to sleep and never hibernate.  Any thoughts, troubleshooting steps, or solutions will of course be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We sometimes get synchronisation glitches if the output from the video source is blanked while the PC handling the sampling is powered up. This makes it look like the card is not responding. I think they are EMS? cards.

Comment: To make it clear, the problem still remains even after the video source is unblanked

Comment: @Tog: Thanks for the comment.  Just to be clear, this is a video *capture* board which formats frames sent by a line scan camera.  Regardless, I don't have access to the internals of the card.  We've noticed that this issue is specific to this customer's environment (> 1000 customers and we've never seen this before).  As we aren't getting much help from the manufacturer I'm just throwing out a rope hoping that someone has encountered something similar which was caused by an OS setting.